Packing a sphere of each integer volume at most $N$ in $\mathbb R^3$ - Does the marginal radius ever approach zero?
Given $N \in \mathbb N$, let $S_i$ denote the sphere of volume $i$ for $i \in \{1, \cdots, N\}$. Now define $r \in \mathbb R$ as the minimal radius so that you can pack all of the spheres into a sphere of radius $r$, allowing the boundary of the packing spheres to touch the sphere of radius $r$, and the boundaries of the spheres can touch each other, but the interiors of each sphere must not intersect.
First I'll show that the map $r(N)$ is monotone by induction. The base case is that $r(1) \le r(2)$ which is trivially true since $N=1$ gives $r=1$ and $N=2$ must have $r>1$. Now suppose that $r(a) \le r(b)$ for all $a \le b$. Now, set $N=a+1$ with radius $r$. Clearly we can simply remove the sphere of radius $a+1$ from the packing, and that gives a valid packing for $N=a$ while only possibly decreasing $r$. Therefore $r$ is monotone increasing as a function of $N$.
Now for my question: What is known about the marginal radius, $\epsilon(N):= |r(N+1) - r(N)|$, as a function of $N$? Could there exist an $N$ where epsilon vanishes? It seems you could prove this false, since the space between each of the spheres in an $N$-packing has to be smaller than the $N+1$ volume sphere, so by adding the a sphere of volume $N+1$, one would think that the minimal packing radius should strictly increase when compared to without the $N+1$ volume sphere and only containing $1\cdots N$. Though if that is proven, how is it specifically done? And what else, if anything, is known for the marginal radius in this case? Perhaps it is a specialization of a more general result packing spheres of various sizes? Obviously you could do circles in 2 dimensions as a first approximation but you can do better by moving into 3d, with all the standard results in packing being applicable.

Given a packing of spheres of volume $1,2,\cdots, N+1$ in a sphere of radius $r(N + 1)$ centered at the origin, we can apply a shrinking linear transform $v \to \sqrt[3]{\frac{N}{N + 1}} v$. This transforms the sphere of volume $i \in \{2,3,\cdots, N + 1\}$ into a sphere of volume $\frac{N}{N + 1} i > i - 1$, and we can fit a sphere of volume $i - 1$ inside the image. So we can pack spheres of volume $1,2,\cdots, N$ in a sphere of radius at most $\sqrt[3]{\frac{N}{N + 1}} r(N + 1)$. Thus we have
$$r(N) \leq \sqrt[3]{\frac{N}{N + 1}} r(N + 1).$$
By volume counting, we have
$$r(N)^3 \gg \sum_{i = 1}^N i \gg N^2$$
so we obtain
$$\epsilon(N) \gg \left(1 - \sqrt[3]{\frac{N}{N + 1}} \right) r(N + 1) \gg N^{-1/3}.$$
I believe it is possible to show the other direction $\epsilon_N \ll N^{-1/3}$, but the argument seems much harder. This follows if we can show that once we pack spheres of volume $N/1000$ to $N$, we can fit the remaining smaller spheres in the gaps, which I intuitively think is true.

According to your question, the volume of the sphere is $i$, not the radius.

Argh, apologies. Of course. Let me delete my comment

I agree we have $\left(\frac{N(N+1)} 2\right)^{1/3} \le r(N) \le \left (\frac {N}{N+1} \right)^{1/3} r(N+1)$. However exactly the algebraic logic arriving $|r(N+1)-r(N)| > 0$ is what I'm trying to find to accept the answer

Perhaps we need $N>1$ and using the strict inequalities, instead of $\le$, in order to achieve it? But just because asymptotically the margin goes like $1/N^{1/3}$ doesn't necessarily that two radii will not change between consecutive values of $N$.

I already showed that $$r(N)\leq (N/N + 1)^{1/3} r(N + 1)$$, so $r(N) < r(N + 1)$ unless $r(N + 1) = 0$, which is impossible.
